# How to customize the default oauth2.0 login page generated by spring security using ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I am new to Spring Boot and Spring Security. For my web-app, I want to create my own login page which will use OAuth2.0 for authentication using Google. By default using Spring Security, we get a login page, but I want to make my own using ReactJS. I have gone through the documentation at [customizing login page](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/login/advanced.html), but I am not finding enough resources online to completely explain how I can customize the login page using ReactJS. Also, I am not able to understand how the connection happens between the React component holding the login page and Spring Security executing OAuth2.0 authentication.

This code below is what is given in the link, with a tip that says: *You need to provide a @Controller with a @RequestMapping("/login/oauth2") that is capable of rendering the custom login page.*
I would appreciate if someone could point me to the proper resource to read up on how to customize the default login page using ReactJS or could give an example and explain. Thank you.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class OAuth2LoginSecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .oauth2Login(oauth2 -> oauth2
                .loginPage("/login/oauth2")
                ...
                .authorizationEndpoint(authorization -> authorization
                    .baseUri("/login/oauth2/authorization")
                    ...
                )
            );
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You most probably can't use React (would need to know what your authorization server is to give a definitive answer).

Login form involved in `authorization_code` flow is not part of your main frontend. It is not even part of your Spring OAuth2 client with `oauth2Login`. **It is served by your authorization server**.

From the documentation you link:

> The default login page shows each configured OAuth Client with its ClientRegistration.clientName as a link

It is pretty clear: what you can configure on the client is not the login form but the page asking the user to choose a "client registration" (for instance when you want to offer users the possibility to choose between "login with Google" and "login with Github"). It happens before login is initiated and is useful only when you have configured more than one `registration` with `authorization_code` as `authorization-grant-type`.

What you should do is refer to your authorization server documentation to figure out how it allows you to customize the login form display. Usually, you can provide some CSS to match your organization visual identity standards (when talking about OAuth2, we are more frequently talking about SSO, and so styling login / registration for an entire organisation rather than a single app, even if you should be able to set a style on a per OAuth2 client basis if you want to).